# Would this be a good approach to capture requests to Amazon S3 objects and authorize certain requests from certain users would within a web app?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-s3, authorization

So here's the problem I have.

I have some objects (files) on Amazon S3, which are not publicly accessible by everyone.

Now I want to build a web app for a service and one of the features of this service is that users can upload files which are saved onto S3 and the user can allow other users of the service (but not the public in general) to access to these files. So I need the app to be able to do the following:

1) Capture the request to the S3 object so that I can record it for analytics and metric purposes.

2) Authenticate the user account making the request to access the S3 object to see if they're authorized to download it.

Now, while I understand that Amazon has S3 IAM policies, I find that they're applied on a per Amazon User, Group and/or Bucket basis so I'm not sure I can solve my problem using S3 IAM policies.

My best guess is to create a route `/request/<oject-id>` on my web app to accept the request, save info about the request for analytics/metric purposes, and then authorize the user making the request based on the file in question, and finally either serve the file (by redirecting the request to S3) or return an error response if the user is not authorized to access the object.

Is this a good way of doing it? Are there any caveats / issues / considerations to this approach? Am wrong about not using IAM policies? If so, am overlooking something?

Also, I should point out that I did small proof-of-concept by testing it on PHP and to redirect the request to Amazon S3 to serve the object I use the `header` command like so:

```
if($allowed) {
    header( "Location: $S3ObjectURL" );
}else
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
```

and while it did work, I'm wondering if I'm doing it correct. Should I be redirecting with a particular HTTP code (`301`, `302`?) and why?

I'd appreciate any suggestions and feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to rely upon IAM for each user of your service. Instead, you can generate a pre-signed URL for each object on your web server and return that to the user so they can use it to download the object. This provides a lot of added security because the URLs are temporary and need to be regenerated each time the user wants to access the object (allowing you to reauthenticate them). Check out the tutorial on how to do this [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).